# How to get ISBN number from a book title and author programmatically? php

Tags: php

I want know if there is a way to get ISBN number from the title of the book and author programmatically using php.

Does Google Books provide any service for that? And how can we use it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Google Books provides an simple GET method that you could use with PHP cURL that will return ISBN:
https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#PerformingSearch

Comment: thank You i got the result but how to get particular ISBN number from that result..

Comment: You'll get back a JSON array that you can parse with the json_decode() function. Here is a tutorial that may help: http://webhole.net/2009/08/31/how-to-read-json-data-with-php/